# Can Azure turn base64 encoded audio file to text using the Speech-To-Text SDK?

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text

I'm experimenting AZURE Speech-to-Text to convert audio to text. For experimentation sake, I'm hardcoding the audio file name. While I'm able to convert a single utterance (using recognize at once function), I'm unable to do the same for longer audios.
Also has someone tried providing base64 encoded format to Azure Speech-To-Text? Are there any examples I can look at. AZURE documentation does not mention anything about base64 formats.
Using the Flask web framework.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=windows,debian&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-gstreamer) try using GStreamer for encoding Audio file to text using text to speech

[image]